# JVM hangs on shutdown

Tags: jvm, shutdown, freeze

My application JVM hangs on shutdown. While in this state I have taken a thread dump using jstack. But its not obvious to me whats causing the hang from this thread dump. Any help will be much appreciated.

I have removed the RUNNABLE threads from the dump.

```
2019-04-26 20:26:11
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode):

"TenantsRegistry-HEARTBEAT" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000055e33475f800 nid=0x24 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2dd9e64000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x000000072c2d1858> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"ExtendedDataCache-HEARTBEAT" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000055e33434a800 nid=0x1f in Object.wait() [0x00007f2dda769000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x000000072c07c0b8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"HikariPool-1 housekeeper" #11 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000055e334244800 nid=0x1e waiting on condition [0x00007f2ddaf09000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000072b87c350> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x000055e33355d000 nid=0x16 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2de1237000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000072aaa7e58> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x000000072aaa7e58> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x000055e33355a000 nid=0x15 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2de1338000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x000000072aaa64d0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x000055e333550000 nid=0x14 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x000055e3335bd000 nid=0x1b waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 420
```

Comment: *"I have removed the RUNNABLE threads from the dump."* - why? the problem is most likely in one of those threads.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that. I wasn't able to copy/paste the full thread dump. Still don't know how to do that.

Comment: Here is the link to the full thread dump: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vqKYlxpmkEtnS6YSM0UgGEz7hKHchl75/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Two kafka-consumer threads prevent application from shutting down. They are the only non-daemon Java threads in the dump.

Comment: Thanks @apangin. I learned something new. So daemon threads can't prevent JVM from exiting. However all user threads have to finish for JVM to exit.